# How to solve npm run dev

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack-cli

Im trying to install npm for first time. When I run npm install, then npm run dev, it say webpack-cli must install.
After I install it, I got this error:

C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\Documents\laravel\pizzahouse> npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development

> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

CLI for webpack must be installed.
webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)

We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): yes
Installing 'webpack-cli' (running 'npm install -D webpack-cli')...

added 34 packages, and audited 1161 packages in 6s

53 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
[webpack-cli] Unknown argument: --hide-modules
? Which flags do you want to use? ...
√ --entry: The entry point(s) of your application e.g. ./src/main.js
√ Which flags do you want to use? · No items were selected
[webpack-cli]
Executing CLI

√ Which flags do you want to use? · No items were selected
[webpack-cli]
Executing CLI

[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset main.js 644 bytes [emitted] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\Documents\laravel\pizzahouse'
webpack 5.3.2 compiled with 1 error in 57 ms
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset main.js 644 bytes [emitted] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\Documents\laravel\pizzahouse'
webpack 5.3.2 compiled with 1 error in 57 ms
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\Documents\laravel\pizzahouse
npm ERR! command failed                                                                               pack/bin/webpack.js --pr
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-30T03_40_34_931Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\Documents\laravel\pizzahouse
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "npm run development"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-30T03_40_34_948Z-debug.log

How to I solve it?

Comment: What do you use to exec those commands PowerShell ?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to use others git?

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Lokman02Naza\Documents\laravel\pizzahouse'

is there a src folder at the location that the ERROR triggers ?

Answer (score 0):

I clean forgot step 1. I simply ran the following in my cmd console which solved my issue.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```